# Locking in MongoDB for a Pintrest like website

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

One of our client projects is a Pinterest like website. It was made with MySQL and CodeIgniter some time back. As they have recently gotten funding and hopefully will get a lot more traffic. We are rebuilding the website and are seriously considering MongoDB as it seems to be one of the more mature NoSQL DB with a big user base.

I know there were some concerns with global locking till version 2.2 post which they were taken care of.

This is my first project with mongodb and NoSQL. I have a question :

- Is the write lock still something that I should be worrying about?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question with that second point, you could write an essay on gotchas for any db in production, let alone MongoDB; however Google is a good friend here searching for "mongodb gotchas" brings up a significant number of informative links. As for locking, it is on database level however, MongoDB does prefer concurrency features over locking, i.e. operations will seceed to other operations when their data is not in RAM etc and operations are designed to hold lock for as little as possible.

Comment: Thanks, got a good reference to gotchas.

Comment: Two recommendations I would add are to first, make sure your data model reflects the shift from a relational db to a document database. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-considerations-for-mongodb-applications for some guidance and links to example data models towards the end. Second, I would definitely perform a load test on on the model you choose with as close to real-world data and use cases as possible. I would do this regardless of what database you are considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research in a few other places indicated that it isn't such a bad thing as it initially sounds like.

Video from 10gen talking about the global lock : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIWVFUtBV1Q ( Skip to 55:00 for the global lock question )

Current version of mongodb : 2.4 -- Global lock removal happened in 2.2
Details: http://blog.serverdensity.com/goodbye-global-lock-mongodb-2-0-vs-2-2/

From watching a couple of other videos on it, the following statements sum up my current understanding of the issue : 

*"10gen rep : The global lock is something we are very serious about. The server wide lock is gone, now it is a database level lock and in the future we plan to make this to collection level.. "*

"If the record you are trying to update is in the RAM, you will not notice the update because its so fast. It sounds really scary but, you shouldn't face too many issues because of this"